# how to replace a line with another/ c++ code

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

I am working on ubuntu. I have a file called test.txt. I would like to replace the second line with another line. How can I do that? I don't want to create a new file and delete the first one.

I would like to specify that the lenght of the new line is the same with the length of the ond one

Comment: Do you want to replace the line by another line of exactly the same length?

Comment: YES! THE lenght of the new line is the same with the lenght of the ond one

Comment: @AngelDream: is it pure ASCII or may you have UTF-8 sequences in this lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const int lineToReplace = 14;
    std::fstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    char line[255];
    for (int i=0; i<lineToReplace-1; ++i) 
        file.getline(line, 255); // This already skips the newline
    file.tellg();
    file << "Your contents here" << std::endl;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `line` can hold up to 254 bytes (plus the null terminator), so if your line takes more than that, adjust accordingly.

Comment: how to change this for replacing the line 14 ?

Comment: Put the getline in a loop to be executed 13 times: `for (int i=0; i<13; ++i) file.getline(line, 255);`;

Comment: it doesn;t change the new line

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small enough you can read it into memory, do whatever modifications you want on the in-memory copy, and the write if back out.

**Edit** Code as requested:

```
// A vector to store all lines
std::vector<std::string> lines;

// The input file
std::ifstream is("test.txt")

// Get all lines into the vector
std::string line;
while (std::getline(is, line))
    lines.push_back(line);

// Close the input file
is.close();

// All of the file is now in memory, each line a single entry in the vector
// "lines". The items in the vector can now be modified as you please.

// Replace the second line with something else
lines[1] = "Something else";

// Open output file
std::ofstream os("test.txt");

// Write all lines to the file
for(const auto& l : lines)
    os << l << '\n';

// All done, close output file
os.close();
```

Comment: To get the file in memory, you might use the `stat(2)` syscall to query the length of the file, then `open(2)` it and `mmap(2)` it. Refere to man pages for details.

Comment: @AngelDream Added a simple example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is Python, but it's significantly more readable and terse for this purpose:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w+') # open for read/write
g = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+') # temp file to build replacement data
g.write(next(f)) # add the first line
next(f) # discard the second line
g.write(second_line) # add this one instead
g.writelines(f) # copy the rest of the file
f.seek(0) # go back to the start
g.seek(0) # start of the tempfile
f.writelines(g) # copy the file data over
f.truncate() # drop the rest of the file
```

You could also use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python3.2/html/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) instead of [`writelines`](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python3.2/html/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) to do block copying between the files.

Comment: Which language is this? Doesn't look like C++ at all.

Comment: oh i didn't even notice he said c++. i'd like to see a c++ solution this terse. OP i recommend you do this in python.

Comment: In a similar not-what-he-asked-for vein, `sed -e '2s/.*/this is definitely the second line/' ~/test_file`

Comment: `I don't want to create a new file and delete the first one`. This does the same in essence: it rewrites the whole file. Worse yet, it reads the whole file in memory first, regardless of the size

Comment: @sehe: Well, depending on the reason of why he doesn't want to write a new file, writing to a temp file then overwriting the original one may still be a solution: If he just wants to avoid losing extended attributes or similar for the file, or have another program keep the file open and track changes, then the temp file, then overwrite scheme solves his problems. Of course if his issue is with the temp file itself, it is no solution. Of course the memory issue remains (if your file fits in memory, there's no reason to use a temp file at all).

Comment: @sehe: there is no such a thing as changing a line without rewriting the whole file unless the new text has the same byte-by-byte size of the previous (which can be tricky for utf-8 unicode sequences). Every application does this under the hood.

Comment: @Paulo: OP clarified the new line will have the exact same length. Thus there's no need to rewrite the posterior lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, without a hard limit on the line length:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("test.txt",std::ios::in|std::ios::out);
    string line;
    string line_new="LINE2";

    // Skip the first line, file pointer points to beginning of second line now.
    getline(file,line);

    fstream::pos_type pos=file.tellg();

    // Read the second line.
    getline(file,line);

    if (line.length()==line_new.length()) {
        // Go back to start of second line and replace it.
        file.seekp(pos);
        file << line_new;
    }

    return 0;
}
```